# nodejs giving error while connecting to the mongodb server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, compiler-errors

while interacting with mongodb in python language it working without any error but in nodejs it is showing me an error everytime can anyone please tell that how can i fix this error.

jsdcaocqocnqiwpocqwnpoqwhowiqcnwq;owaqcwqndowjcojwqncwqconwqwjoqdhc9ocwq

this is the source code of the program:

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
import assert from 'assert';

const url='mongodb://localhost:27017';

const dbname='myProject';

const client =new MongoClient(url);

client.connect((err)=>{
  assert.equal(null,err);
  console.log("connected sucessfully");

  const db=client.db(dbname);

  client.close();
});
```

here is the error:

```
const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);
                                     ^

MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\hasan\mong\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:278:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 1070637,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\hasan\mong\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:379:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hasan\mong\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:285:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:632:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
          [cause]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {},
  [cause]: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
      at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\hasan\mong\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:379:20)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hasan\mong\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:285:22)
      at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:632:26)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
      at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
    [cause]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16) {
      errno: -4078,
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '::1',
      port: 27017
    }
  }
}
```

solution for this error

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017` means nothing is listening on the port, and that the client is using the IPv6 address.  Try searching SO for that string.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some ip config issue, so try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. it should work.

OR

you can set bindIp in your mongo config as

```
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1, ::1
```